# Microsoft Access ledger

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to making a ledger in access. What I'm trying to accomplish is making a query like this. This is the output that I want:

[image]

this is my query

```
SELECT drvYourTable.TransDate, drvYourTable.DrAmount,
    drvYourTable.CrAmount,
    (Select Sum(DrAmount - CrAmount)
        From tblYourtable
        Where tblYourtable.TransDate >= drvYourtable.TransDate
    ) AS Balance
FROM tblYourTable AS drvYourTable
ORDER BY drvYourTable.TransDate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably miss *Nz*:

```
SELECT 
    drvYourTable.TransDate, 
    drvYourTable.DrAmount,
    drvYourTable.CrAmount,
    (Select Sum(Nz(DrAmount, 0) - Nz(CrAmount, 0))
        From tblYourtable
        Where tblYourtable.TransDate >= drvYourtable.TransDate
    ) AS Balance
FROM 
    tblYourTable AS drvYourTable
ORDER BY 
    drvYourTable.TransDate;
```